# Why Run-time error '3061'. Too few parameters. Expected 1? Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have researched all the STACKOVERFLOW questions on this but cannot make it work.  I have a simple table:

[image]

And a form:

[image]

I want to extract the fields from the table T:ActityRoster and the “Activity Date” from the form and “add” them to a table T:ActivityHistory.

[image]

A STACKOVERFLOW expert helped me with some code, but it won’t even set the first recordset:rsIn

```vb
Dim ActID As Integer, actDate As Date, val1 As Long, val2 As Long, val3 As Boolean, val4 As Currency

Dim db As Database, rsIn As Recordset, rsOut As Recordset

Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb

ActID = Me.cboActivityName.Column(0)

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM T:ActivityRoster WHERE [ActivityID] = ActID"

Debug.Print strSQL

Set rsIn = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)

rsIn.MoveLast

Set rsOut = db.OpenRecordset("T:AttendanceHistory", dbOpenDynaset, dbEditAdd)

rsOut.MoveLast

actDate = Me.ActivityDate.Value  ' retrive the date from the form

With rsIn
    .MoveFirst
    Do
    val1 = !ActivityID
    val2 = !MemberID
    val3 = !Attended
    val4 = !AmtSpent

           With rsOut
               .AddNew
               !ActivityDate = actDate
               !ActivityID = val1
               !MemberID = val2
               !Attended = val3
               !AmtSpent = val4
               .Update
           End With

    .MoveNext
    Loop Until .EOF
    .Close

End With

rsOut.Close
Set rsIn = Nothing
Set rsOut = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have verified that all field names are correct and are consistent data types. When I put the query back into Access, it gives what is expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `SELECT` statement includes the name of a VBA variable (*ActID*):

```sql
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM T:ActivityRoster WHERE [ActivityID] = ActID"
```

Unfortunately, the db engine doesn't know anything about that variable.  So, when it sees *ActID*, it presumes that is the name of a parameter for which you haven't supplied a value.

Include the variable's value instead of its name when you build the `SELECT` statement.  Use one of these 2 examples: the first if `[ActivityID]` is text datatype; or the second if it's numeric datatype:

```sql
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [T:ActivityRoster] WHERE [ActivityID] = '" & ActID & "'"
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [T:ActivityRoster] WHERE [ActivityID] = " & ActID
```

I enclosed the table name in square brackets because that name includes punctuation.  However, I would rename the table if possible.  Same for *T:AttendanceHistory*.  Choose object names which do not include punctuation and spaces and which do not match VBA or SQL keywords.

Alternatively you could use a parameter query and supply the parameter value with *ActID*:

```vb
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [T:ActivityRoster] WHERE [ActivityID] = [which_ActivityID]"
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strSQL)
qdf.Parameters("which_ActivityID").Value = ActID
Set rsIn = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)
```

Comment: OUTSTANDING.  made all the changes and it almost worked.  I have some blank fields so it gives an error 94 Invalid use of Null....any suggestions?

Comment: I tried this     If IsNull(!AmtSpent) Then
    val4 = "$0.00"
    Else
    val4 = !AmtSpent
    End If

Answer (score 0):

My source was a query and it had criteria in it referencing a field on a form. Got rid of that and all is now okay.  All my fields in the query were the right name, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A little old, but I ran into this issue today and required a different solution. So hopefully this helps out anyone who runs into this in the future.

I had this error pop up when I created a new query and tried to reference it in VBA:

```vb
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM qry_New WHERE [Field]='" & [RptField] & "'")
```

Compiling the project seemed to resolve the error. **Debug > Compile [Project Name]** in the VB Editor.

This was also in Access 2013, not Access 2010, so I'm not sure if it applies in this exact scenario.